# Test if application has windows on current space

Tags: applescript, safari, spaces

Scripting different desktops in recent macOS versions is difficult, but one scenario I wanted to accomplish is to open a document in Safari in a specific window:

- If a Safari window is open in the current space, open a new tab in that window.
- Otherwise, make a new window in the current space and open it there.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 5):

For some strange reason, in System Events, **the windows of a process only include windows on the active space**. Using this tidbit, I was able to cobble together a solution to this.

```
on count_windows_on_current_space(process_name)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process process_name
            return count of windows
        end tell
    end tell
end count_windows_on_current_space

tell application "Safari"
    if my count_windows_on_current_space("Safari") = 0 then
        make new document
    end if
    open location "https://cgamesplay.com/"
end tell
```

Comment: Why within the _block_ of the `on count_windows_on_current_space(process_name)` _handler_ do you have `tell process "Safari"` when it should really be `tell process process_name`? Otherwise when using the _handler_, e.g. `count_windows_on_current_space(TextEdit)`, the TextEdit _process_ is never queried.

Comment: Also, I hate to tell you this, but this does not work properly all the time! For example, two Desktops, the first one has two or more Safari windows, but one of the windows is minimized. Now (before or after fixing the issue pointed out in the first comment) you run your AppleScript _code_ from the second Desktop and it will return `1`, not `0` as one might expect. So it's back to the drawing board!

Comment: I look at this issue a while back and the only solution I could think of using normal basic AppleScript was to check to see if the target App has any minimized windows and restore them first. This caused an issue if the minimized window is on a different Desktop by switching back to that Desktop, which defeated the purpose of what was being done at the time. It also was visually disruptive.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I've fixed the code snippets, but you're right. In the future I might try counting non-minimized windows, which in my use case would be fine: if the window is minimized, create a new one.

Comment: Re: "I might try counting non-minimized windows" ... Then how are you going to tell if the Desktop you're at doesn't have a normal window showing? I've been down that road and because the _code_ you have is't accurate what _code_ would you use?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I was going to see if it were possible to lis the windows from the application object, then correlate the IDs with windows from the process object. Not sure if it would work, but that's my best guess for now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to unminimize all the windows in their respective desktops with the following code

```
tell application "Safari"
    try
        set miniaturized of windows to false
    end try
end tell
```

Then I use your code mixed with other bits I found online.
I have 4 tabs pinned so the first tab a new window opens is index = 5
The code checks to see if a window is active and opens a new tab.
if there is no window, opens a new window, which comes with a tab I want to get rid of and opens a new tab with raindrop (tab manager)
to finish, it does cmd+l to focus on the url bar.

this is the full code

```
tell application "Safari"
    try
        set miniaturized of windows to false
    end try
end tell

on count_windows_on_current_space(process_name)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process process_name
            return count of windows
        end tell
    end tell
end count_windows_on_current_space

if application "Safari" is running then
    tell application "Safari"
        if my count_windows_on_current_space("Safari") = 0 then
            make new document
            open location "https://app.raindrop.io/"
            activate
            tell window 1
                close (tabs where index = 5)
            end tell
            delay 1
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "l" using command down
            
        else
            open location "https://app.raindrop.io/"
            activate
            delay 1
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "l" using command down
        end if
    end tell
    
else
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        open location "https://app.raindrop.io/"
        delay 1
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "l" using command down
    end tell
end if
```